# How to Disable ReorderableListView Reorder capability but still allow scrolling?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do we deactivate the ReorderableListView dragging/reordering capabilities in Flutter?

I would like to disable the dragging function but still allow scrolling.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: using which language? u tag android, ios, flutter, dart...

Comment: @FahimParkarSorry, its flutter

Comment: Can you drop a code of what You've already tried?

Answer (score 4):

Just add inside ReorderableListView

> buildDefaultDragHandles: false,

Comment: This worked for me in flutter 3.5.5 and looks cleaner than the ignore pointer.

Comment: That's a really clean answer. I just added a buildDefaultDragHandles: 1 < childTiles.length, so that the reorder only functions when the list has more than 1 item.

Answer (score 3):

One way to disable reordering is by setting parameter `buildDefaultDragHandles` of `ReorderableListView.builder()` to `false`.

For example, if you'd like to enable reordering only if there are at least two items in the list, you could do something like:

```
ReorderableListView.builder(
  itemCount: someList.length,
  itemBuilder: _buildListWidget,
  buildDefaultDragHandles: someList.length > 1, // disable drag&drop if there's only one item
  onReorder: onReorderList,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your list item in an IgnorePointer widget and control with a bool, like this

```
class ReorderableList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ReorderableListState createState() => _ReorderableListState();
}

class _ReorderableListState extends State<ReorderableList> {
  bool _allowReorder = true;

  final List<int> _items = List<int>.generate(50, (int index) => index);

  void reorderData(int oldindex, int newindex) {
    setState(() {
      if (oldindex < newindex) {
        newindex -= 1;
      }
      final int item = _items.removeAt(oldindex);
      _items.insert(newindex, item);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _allowReorder = !_allowReorder;
        });
      }),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ReorderableListView(
                onReorder: (one, two) => reorderData(one, two),
                children: <Widget>[
                  for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index++)
                    if (_allowReorder)
                      ListTile(
                        key: Key('$index'),
                        title: Text('Item ${_items[index]}'),
                      )
                    else
                      IgnorePointer(
                        key: Key('$index'),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text('Item ${_items[index]}'),
                        ),
                      )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```